# Extract value from a string occurring after a particular word

Tags: regex, hive

A json script is passed as a string and I need to extract the numeric value after the `content_id` for further mapping. Sample Data below:

```
{"url": {"phone": "videos/hssportint/hssport/jocaasd/6_3818e20a9e/19098311205/phone", "tv": "/mnt/c81292786e1e368e12144c302007/output/", "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1", "subsample": 25,  "content_id": "1000231205", "encryption_enabled": false, "non_ad_time_intervals": [2330.68, 2898.36]], "packager_path": "/opt/bento4"}}], "vmaf_path": "/vmaf"}
```

The parameters are dynamic so I can't extract using a substr function or count to extract after certain number of occurrences of a special character.

Comment: JSON and regex are not good friends, use a parser.

Answer (score 0):

JSON in your example is malformed, it contains extra `]` and some tail after closing `}`. For correct JSON you can use `get_json_object`, for example:

```
select get_json_object(src_json,'$.url.content_id') from
    (
     select '{"url": {"phone": "videos/hssportint/hssport/jocaasd/6_3818e20a9e/19098311205/phone", "tv": "/mnt/c81292786e1e368e12144c302007/output/", "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1", "subsample": 25,  "content_id": "1000231205", "encryption_enabled": false, "non_ad_time_intervals": [2330.68, 2898.36], "packager_path": "/opt/bento4"}}' as src_json 
     )s
    ;
```

Result:

```
OK
1000231205
Time taken: 21.606 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regexp_extract](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) funciton in hive with matching regex to extract only the digits from content_id.

**Example:**

```
select regexp_extract(col1,'"content_id":\\s"(\\d+)"',1) from (
select string('{"url": {"phone": "videos/hssportint/hssport/jocaasd/6_3818e20a9e/19098311205/phone", "tv": "/mnt/c81292786e1e368e12144c302007/output/", "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1", "subsample": 25,  "content_id": "1000231205", "encryption_enabled": false, "non_ad_time_intervals": [2330.68, 2898.36]], "packager_path": "/opt/bento4"}}], "vmaf_path": "/vmaf"}')col1
)t;
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 1000231205  |
+-------------+--+
```

Regex description:

```
"content_id":\\s"(\\d+)" //match literal "content_id": + any space + "digit inside quotes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an expensive way to do it through a combination of regex and substring functions

```
substr(split(regexp_extract(message,'content_id([^&]*)'), '"')[3],1) as content_id
```